# Watson API Call failing

Tags: android-studio, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

[image]
I am doing an API call from Android Studio. There is no errror but when I do Run at ADB, my app stops saying "Unfortunately the app has stopped" Can anyone please see and tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Workspace ID for your application, do you understand?

Example:

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService("08-11-2016");
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}", "{password}");

MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
  .inputText("Turn on the lights")
  // Replace with the context obtained from the initial request
  //.context(...)
  .build();

String **workspaceId** = "**ID from your conversation...**";

MessageResponse response = service 
  .message(workspaceId, newMessage)
  .execute();

System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sayuri, i tried your way of the code, its apk app on my phone as well as while running via ADB, its crashing.